# NuGet restore issue when downloading solutions from github

Tags: visual-studio, github, nuget-package-restore

I have a project on Github which I have made on my laptop https://github.com/Mech0z/Foosball9000

However now I am on my desktop and I have trouble getting the solution to compile and I am not sure why NuGet do not want to restore my packages?

Its packages like System.Web.Http and Castle Windsor, stuff that should get restored if I look in my packages.config

I am running VS 2015 Enterprice RC, but I have seen the same issue in VS 2013

[image: Right click and view source to see full image]

Comment: If you don't have "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" configured in your Tools->Options->NuGet Package Restore" settings, you may run into this. I _believe_ enabling nuget package restore at the solution level is no longer necessary with later versions, either, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I do have that, and no "enable nuget package restore" was removed as of 2013 I think, at least its not in 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so grabbed the project from GitHub and attempted to build (but failed as you did). Your build status in your README is saying it can't get a build up either.

Did some digging though, it appears your [FoosballOld.csproj](https://github.com/Mech0z/Foosball9000/blob/master/src/FoosballOld/FoosballOld/FoosballOld.csproj) has a lot of broken references (based on its location being so deep in the project). Keep in mind that NuGet's default behavior is to restore packages to "packages" along side your .sln file. So, given your FoodBalOld.csproj is in src/FoosballOld/FoosballOld, referencing `../packages` isn't going to work:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

With that said, I would advise you update these references (if you're intending to keep this file structure, changing them to `..\..\..\packages` should work).

Once I changed that:

```
Build Summary
-------------
00:02.670 - Success - Debug Any CPU - src\FoosballOld\FoosballOld\FoosballOld.csproj
00:00.527 - Success - Debug Any CPU - http://localhost:2521
00:00.005 - Success - Debug Any CPU - Models\Models.csproj
00:00.003 - Success - Debug Any CPU - MongoDBRepository\MongoDBRepository.csproj
00:00.002 - Success - Debug Any CPU - Logic\Logic.csproj

Total build time: 00:02.856

========== Build: 5 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped, Completed at 5/3/2015 9:42:20 AM ==========
```

To the original point, I have NuGet package restore set on build:

[image: NuGet Settings]

If you don't have this defined, you'll probably have to right-click your project individually and open "Manage Nuget Packages...". In that window, you should see an alert at the top to restore packages.

This is all assuming you have NuGet installed within visual studio. If you don't, you'll need to "Enable NuGet package restore" at the solution level I believe.

Comment: Is there a place I can see that error? Because I just got the "missing assesmbly" would be nice if I could see the nuget errors, saying "I cant restore this as this path is invalid" or something similar

Comment: Just simply expanded the references and looked for those with errors. From there, I examined the properties and saw the path misaligned. I've run into this before though, so probably just past experience that makes it easier.

Comment: If you were so inclined, you could make a target file that defines the nugget package directory. Then instead of using relative paths, use something like `$(NuGetDir)\packages\...`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) will try to remember next time I see those little yellow marks at my references